# Wordpress, allowing commenters to edit there own comments?

Tags: wordpress, permissions, comments, edit

On a Wordpress blog I'm building, the user must sign up to comment, when they sign up they are added as a subscriber with minimal permissions.

I was wondering how a add permissions to this user so they can only edit there own comments?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

place the following code in function.php:

```
$subscriber= get_role('subscriber');
$subscriber->add_cap('edit_comment');
```

eidt_comment is only supported in verson 3.1 or newer